# Explanation on how this bit of code works

Tags: python

```
def missing_char(str,n):
    front = str[:n]
    back = str[n+1:]
    return front + back
```

I don't really understand what is being said when back is defined, and furthermore I don't understand how this actually takes out the letter you specify when you enter a word into the function with the "return front + back" part.

Thanks everyone for the help, you all made me understand it better :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`str[:n]` copies the string from the start up to, but not including, the n:th character.
`str[n+1:]` copies the string from the (n+1):th character to the end.

Adding both these strings will result in all the characters of the original string, *except* for the n:th character.

`str[:n]` is a shorthand for `str[0:n]`, and `str[n:]` is a shorthand for `str[n:len(str)]`.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, don't forget to click the accept button. And, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Another way to put it: it's a way to do `del sequence[n:n+1]` on an immutable sequence like a string or a tuple.

Comment: @Djj: No, you didn't. There shoul be a green ✓ on the left. Click on the outlined ✓ of your favourite answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
front = str[:n] 
# get prefix of str with n characters
# for str = "hello" and n=2 front = "he"

back = str[n+1:] 
# get suffix of the string starting from n+1th character
# for str = "hello" and n=2 back = "lo"

front + back 
# concatenation of front + back, which is "he" + "lo" = "helo"
# So this small method basically removes the nth character
```

Answer (score 2):

`front` is calculated as all letters in `str` up to position `n`, then `back` is calculated as all letters in `str` from position `n+1` - ie skipping the letter at `n` itself. Then `front + back` simply concatenates the two fragments back together and returns the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at `"Hello, World!"` and take out character 5 (who needs punctuation anyway).

When you call `missing_char`, you get the following steps:

1. `front` is set to "Hello" (the characters from zero to n)
2. `back` is set to " World!" (the characters from `n+1` to the end)
3. The concatenation of front and back is returned, basically putting `back` on the end of `front`, resulting in our final answer of "Hello World!".

You may want to look at splicing in more detail, something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) is really good for that. It is a very powerful feature once understand.